# JQuery + Nuget Package management default installation location

Tags: nuget

So I just installed JQuery into my project via Nuget. But based on my companies coding standards all scripts must exist in:

/Assets/Scripts

Nuget installs it via /Scripts

Is there anyway I can change this default setting? So when I perform an update it will update in the right location?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, this is not supported yet, a nuget codeplex issue is here http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1914 for comments/vote.

Answer (score 0):

This might be unrelated but I had a similar issue with my C# NuGet DLLs.  I was told to put them in the 3rd party library and not in my solution path so here is what I had to do.

1. Create a text file called "nuget.config" in my the root of my Visual Studio solution
2. Modify that file to point to the repository location

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <settings>
     <repositoryPath>C:...\3rdPartyLibs\packages
   </settings>

Here is the offical [NuGet Config Settings](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-settings) page.  Although NuGet gives you a specific XML format to use, that format didn't work for me and thanks to another post that I can't find, the above xml file works.